# Are the Factors of N more than zero but less than (.......)?

Tags: education

<del>I want to know how to prove that the divisors of any number are always less than that number (divided by two).</del>

<del>Are the Factors of N  more than zero but less than (N/2) ?</del>

<del>Excuses me if this question is Wrong.</del>

Edit: I want the Question to be more clear so that when someone else reads it they will understand what i asked so i am restating the question.

Question: Given A Positive Integer N are its factors More than or equal 2 but less than or equal n/2 Ignoring 1 And N itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0*d=N $ is impossible so $0$ isn't a factor of any number but $0$.

By definition factors are integers.  By convention they are positive.  (Otherwise we'd go nuts making exceptions and always pointing out if $a|b$ then negative $a $ also divides $b $.

$1$ and $N $ are always factors and $N>N/2$ so you need to restate your proposition.

Proposition:  if $d$ is a non-trivial factor of $N$ (non-trivial means $d\ne 1$ and $d\ne N $) then $d \le N/2$.

Proof:  if $d|N$ then there exists positive integer $m $ so that $dm=N$. That means $d=N/m $.

$m\ne 1$ because $d*1\ne N$.  So $m\ge 2$.  So $1/m \le 1/2$ and $d=N/m \le N/2$.

Comment: Thank you exactly the answer i wanted, and sorry for not Asking the question more clearly i have restated it.

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is clearly a factor of $N$ and is also bigger than $\frac{N}{2}$.

Otherwise, if there is a factor $d$ of $N$ greater than $\frac{N}{2}$, $\frac{N}{d}$ is less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question as "are the divisors of N *fewer* than N/2"?
This is obviously not true for several small numbers: e.g. 2 and 3 have 2 divisors, 4 has 3 divisors, 6 and 8 have 4 divisors, 12 has 6 divisors.